# Tree view vs embedded tags: data representation in XML

Tags: xml, tree

I am a XML novice and I am writing a parser for natural language that outputs data in an XML-like (but rather tree-like) format. Here's how an element within a root tag looks:

```
<text>
    <paragraph>This is the first sentence. This is the second sentence.</paragraph>
      <sentence>This is the first sentence.</sentence>
        <word>This</word>
        <word>is</word>
        <word>the</word>
        <word>first</word>
        <word>sentence</word>
      <sentence>This is the secondsentence.</sentence>
        <word>This</word>
        <word>is</word>
        <word>the</word>
        <word>second</word>
        <word>sentence</word>
</text>
```

As you can see, I am basically doing a tree view using XML-like tags to show every step of decomposition. **How can I make this a proper XML while retaining this tree-like structure?** Because of how the text is parsed I would like to avoid doing something like that:

```
<text><paragraph><sentence><word>This</word> <word>is</word> <word>the</word> <word>first</word> <word>sentence</word>.</sentence></paragraph></text>
```

I am aware that I can make mixed content:

```
<sentence>This is the first sentence.
  <word>This</word>
  <word>is</word>
  <word>the</word>
  <word>first</word>
  <word>sentence</word>
</sentence>
```

But that solution doesn't seem very elegant. Another option I see is to move every stage of decomposition a child. Or is there a more elegant way of doing that?

Answer (score 0):

The correct solution is the one you want to avoid:

```
<text><paragraph><sentence><word>This</word> <word>is</word> <word>the</word> <word>first</word> <word>sentence</word>.</sentence></paragraph></text>
```

So we need to understand why you want to avoid it.

Note that it's quite possible to output something different as the immediate output of your natural language parser, and then post-process it into the correct format using one or more XSLT transformations.

To be honest, I'm not sure what you are asking. Are you asking for help designing the XML format? SO discourages design questions. One of the reasons is that getting the design right involves a lot more information than you've given us (for example, who is using the output you are producing, and what are they using it for).

Or are you asking how to generate the format you want to produce? In that case, we need to know a lot more about your natural language parser and the constraints it imposes.

Comment: I am pretty happy with my current XML design. The biggest constraint here is that I extract and slightly modify elements from each sentence, i.e. I drop part of the punctuation, bring some items to lowercase and so forth. Hence my output differs from the input, so I cannot just replace the original text with it's tagged version (I want to keep both). I also consider making 2 children to each parent: the original string of the previous stage plus a container of all tagged elements, which then split into two children etc. My problem is more about the good practice in XML for making it parseable.